# Combined OR and AND query for elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, opensearch

Can someone please help to create elastic search query for below case scenario.

```
((Field1=Keyword1 AND Field2=Keyword1) OR (Field1=Keyword2 AND Field2=Keyword2) OR ...
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's basically a top-level `bool/should` with nested `bool/filter`

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "Field1": "Keyword1"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "Field2": "Keyword1"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "Field1": "Keyword2"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "Field2": "Keyword2"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one of the simplest you can use is [Query String](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) type of query from Elasticsearch. this will create `bool` query internally.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "((Field1:Keyword1 AND Field2:Keyword1) OR (Field1:Keyword2 AND Field2:Keyword2) OR (Field2:Keyword2))"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: One word of caution with `query_string`, though, is that it [can error out](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) if you blindly use your users' query content that can be malformed. A safer approach is to use [`simple_query_string` instead](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html)

Comment: @Val agree with you !!!